# Can logstash access a redis input via ssl?

Tags: ssl, redis, logstash

I'm setting up a cloud service on azure and want to buffer logs in redis. However running redis as a web service on azure means my requests have to leave my virtual network, which means encryption is a must.

I've searched for hours but haven't found any clues whether logstash can read from redis via ssl. Isn't that possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like redis isn't able to talk ssl and the redis web service of azure seems to come with custom ssl support, which seems to be the reason why there is no ssl support for the redis input.

However this solution (stunnel) helped me solving my problem: http://bencane.com/2014/02/18/sending-redis-traffic-through-an-ssl-tunnel-with-stunnel/